# Why am I not getting proper output response in Simulink?

Tags: simulation, control, control-system, matlab, simulink

I am trying to implement PID control loop for flight control of Quanser VTOL(vertical take off and Landing system) in Simulink.

VTOL Information book is placed at link below:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/yszb2ytbjv5966k/Info_book.pdf/file

Please check the last pages specifically last two pages.

I have made my model in Simulink 2015 and i also uploaded my model on media fire,link is given below:

https://www.mediafire.com/file/8lp26beyo5ofbu7/CS_Lab7_loop.slx/file

I am trying to get graph like the one in attached snap(this graph appears on last page of book). I have also attached snap of control loop(it is shown on pg 22/26 in book). I have also attached of my simulink model. **My issue is that my simulink graph response is not matching that in book.  I have made my simulink model exactly like the PID control loop shown on pg 22/26 and i have used exactly same values of variables like K, Kt etc but i am not getting proper response, instead i am getting a decaying(damped) response. I have changed the limits of  saturation block but still this damping persists**

[image]
[image]
[image]

My MATLAB code for variables/parameters values is:

```
clc
clear
close all
J=0.0035
K=0.0373
Kt=0.0108
L=53.8*10^-3
R=3
B=0.002
kp=1.5
kd=2
ki=3
```

**Update** I am attaching a new snap where i have changed limits of saturation block and now its limits are 0 to 4 and now graph shape becomes relatively reasonable. I can not entirely remove this block as it is also included in the snap shown on book
[image]

Comment: what does happen if you increase the duty cycle of the pulse ?

Comment: Try to use built-in pid block rather than using separate gain blocks for proportional,integral and derivative gains

Comment: As @Rahmany has said. The `Figure 4.6` from the manufacturer indicates that the rise time is nearly 1 second and the input command given appears to be of `1/6 Hz` frequency. Try changing the input command to the same frequency and duty cycle.

Comment: @Rahmany no change in output, if i increase duty cycle of rectangular

Comment: @AJN no change in output, if i change frequency  of rectangular pulse source.

Comment: @DSPCS. Yes damping is almost eliminated by using  bulit in PID block.

Comment: what's the step response? can you update your post with its graph?

Comment: Remove the saturation block; it may be getting falsely triggered. Your post has insufficient information.

Comment: @AJN thanks for your suggestion regarding saturation block. I can not entirely remove this block as it is also included in the snap shown on book. So i changed limits and that solved issue

Comment: If it solved your issue, you can post it as an answer below and mark it as solved. That is allowed in SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i changed the limits of saturation block,damping was no more there.For this purpose i used lower limit value as '0' and upper limit value as '4'.